# Is there a way in php to extract any string between those quotes and all the other text, and variables

Tags: extract

Is there a way using php to extract a string from here. Ive found other posts but i think this one may be harder, because the string may include quotes or other characters in itself.

String is like this, with some variable parts and other constant, that i will point to you:

```
<base href="http://www.domain.com/folder/" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


<meta name="description" content="What about having a look at those webs. "/>
```

It is all that including the line breaks.

Im targeting what would be inside the content part of meta name and between the quotes:

```
What about having a look at those webs.
```

This parts are constant:

```
<base href="" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


<meta name="description" content=""/>
```

while these parts are variable:

```
http://www.domain.com/folder/



What about having a look at those webs.
```

How could php look for the pattern:

```
<meta name="description" content="
```

and print everything following until it finds pattern:

```
"/>
```

Other replies use very long regex to strip, but im unsure this could be done with a long paragraph like this and with multiple strings changing, so maybe there is a way to look for patterns and chop this.

The string is the output of a smarty.

Comment: HTML attributes quoted with double quotes can not legally contain strings that contain double quotes.  The double quotes should have been converted to &quot; (eg by Smarty).  Is this really your input text?  Invalid HTML?

Comment: You are right, ive used a test template in localhost to check the output and then written the content by hand, dont know why i went with the idea to quote that word, excuse me.